# Modify Code - Delete Row If Cell Has any Data - Google Sheets / Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to modify this code so that if there is **any data**(Numbers as well) in column 7, it will delete the entire row.

Currently whatever you put into the inverted commas in the If Statement, it deletes

what could you substitute that would do that ?

```
function DeleteCOMPLETED2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('RELOCATION'), true);
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[7] == "**if there is any data in column 7 then delete entire row**") {
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete row if anything in column7

```
function DeleteCOMPLETED2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RELOCATION');
  var values=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d=0;
  values.forEach(function(r,i){if(r[6]){sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);}});//column7
}
```